# How to access nested tables in hdf5 with pandas

Tags: pandas, hdf5

I want to retrieve a table from an HDF5 file using pandas.

Following several references I found, I have tried to open the file using:

```
df = pd.read_hdf('data/test.h5', g_name),
```

where g_name is the path to the object I want to retrieve, i.e. the table TAB1, for instance, MAIN/Basic/Tables/TAB1.

g_name is retrieved as follows:

```
def get_all(name):
    if 'TAB1' in name:
        return name

with h5py.File('data/test.h5') as f:
    g_name = f.visit(get_all)
    print(g_name)
    group = f[g_name]
    print(type(group))
```

I have also tried retrieving the object itself, as seen in the above code snippet, but the object type is 

How would I convert this to something I can read as a data frame in pandas?

For the first case, I get the following error: 
"cannot create a storer if the object is not existing "

I do not understand why it cannot find the object, if the path is the same as retrieved during the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution:

```
hf = h5py.File('data/test.h5')
data = hf.get('MAIN/Basic/Tables/TAB1')
result = data[()]

# This last step just converts the table into a pandas df
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```